# Error in regex to catch special characters

Tags: java, regex

i wrote a regular expression to catch special characters in an input string but it catches the numbers as well. Here is the regex,

```
final String REGEX="[^.,%*$#@?^<!&>'|/\\\\~\\[\\]{}+-=\"]*";
```

I need to catch the above mentioned characters only. Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You created a range with the unescaped hyphen.

The misplaced hyphen makes the pattern match these characters:

[image]

Escape the hyphen or place at the end of the class:

```
final String REGEX="[^.,%*$#@?^<!&>'|/\\\\~\\[\\]{}+=\"-]*";
                                                      ^
```

Here is [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wQ8vD5/2)

Comment: Looks like OP wants the negation to be there, since the caret is also present elsewhere in the expression. I guess the regexp is used to filter out unwanted characters.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: OK, let's wait for feedback. I reverted the answer to just fix the hyphen issue.

Comment: You really didn't deserve to be downvoted. I'll compensate by upvoting you for your nice infographic :)

Answer (score 2):

Move the hyphen (`-`) to the end of your character class:

```
final String REGEX="[^.,%*$#@?^<!&>'|/\\\\~\\[\\]{}+=\"-]*"
```

Where it's currently positioned (`+-=`), it expresses a range from `+` to `=`. This range includes, a.o. all digits.