# Matcher cannot recognize the second group of regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex

I've got a problem when I'm using Matcher for finding a symbol from the group of regular expressions, it cannot recognize the second group .Maybe the code below make it clear :

```
public void set(String n){
String pat = "(\\d+)[!@#$%^&*()_+-=}]";
Pattern r;
r = Pattern.compile(pat);
System.out.println(r);
Matcher m;
m = r.matcher(n);
if (m.find()) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
              "Not a correct form", "ERROR_NAME_MATCH", 0);
}else{
     name = n;
}
}
```

After running the code the first group is recognizable but the second one [!@#$%^&*()_+-=}] is not.I'm totally sure that the expression is true I've checked it with 'RegexBuddy'. There must be a problem with concatenating two or more groups in one line.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: The  `+-=` create a range, BTW, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32324595/error-in-regex-to-catch-special-characters/32324646#32324646. The `-` must be put at the end of the character class. What is `n`?

Comment: You know that only `(` `)` create a group? `[` `]` are just for set of characters.

Comment: Show us the input data and what output you expect from them.

Comment: If the hyphen issue is the only one, I am closing as a dupe.

Comment: I've changed the place of characters as you said ,but the problem is still there.

Comment: yes i  know that.@krzyk

Comment: As an example a string like that must be recognized: "ili@ya$".
@krzyk

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: it is not about the hyphen , I've already said that I changed regex but the problem is there and the link you've mentioned  : (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32324595/error-in-regex-to-catch-special-characters) does not answer my question.

Comment: Try with input `il1@ya$` and you'll get a match from `([0-9]+)[!@#$%^&*()_+=-}]` or from `([0-9]+)[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]`

Comment: If you want to check if a string has a digit or a character from the specified set, I think all you need is `[!@#$%^&*()_+=}0-9-]`

Answer (score 1):

Your regex - `(\d+)[!@#$%^&*()_+=}-]` - matches a *sequence* of 1+ digits followed with a symbol from the specified set.

You want to test a string and return `true` if a single character from the specified set is present in the string.

So, just move `\d` to the character class and certainly move the `-` to the end of this class:

```
String pat = "[\\d!@#$%^&*()_+=}-]";
               ^^^
```

If you need to match a digit or special char, use

```
String pat = "\\d|[!@#$%^&*()_+=}-]";
```

If you need both irrespective of the order:

```
String pat = "^(?=\\D*\\d)(?=[^!@#$%^&*()_+=}-]*[!@#$%^&*()_+=}-])";
```

Comment: I finally find what I'm looking for :    ` String pat = "(\\d*)[!@#$%^&*()_+=}-]"; `
The expression you gave has only one problem , I want to find integer or Special character or BOTH .

Comment: If you need the digit or special char, use `String pat = "\\d|[!@#$%^&*()_+=}-]";`.

Comment: Note that you cannot test for a digit or for second or for both with one regex. See my two additional patterns at the bottom..