# Python regular expression dot character

Tags: python, regex

I have solved this problem via Wiktor Stribiżew's suggestion.

Edited: I only need to extract the first element of the list at a time, because I need to do other operations on that number. I use a loop in my code just for testing.

I want to split an arithmetic expression into a list of numbers.

For example: 1+0.2-(3^4)*5 -> ['1', '0.2', '3', '4', '5']

I use the re library in python, but the expression is split with a dot character '.' although I do not include '.' in the delmiters.

Namely, when input is 1+0.2, the output will be ['1', '0', '2'], which should be ['1', '0.2']

The code is below:

```
#!/bin/python
import re

delims = re.compile(r"[+-/*///^)]")

while True:
    string = input()
    res = list()
    i = 0
    while i < len(string):
        if string[i] >= '0' and string[i] <= '9':
            num_str = delims.split(string[i:], 1)[0]
            res.append(num_str)
            i += len(num_str) - 1
        i += 1
    print(res)
```

I really appreciate any opinion to this question!

Comment: The `-` creates a range, escape it or move to the end / start of the char class, use `[-+/*^)]`

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32324595/error-in-regex-to-catch-special-characters/32324646#32324646) is a similar question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are brilliant!

Comment: You can accept Sebastian's answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your approach is not working is that you create a character range with `+-/` which contains the dot. I also think you are overcomplicating things.

```
import re
str = '1+0.2-(3^4)*5'
res = re.split(r'[-+()/*^]+', str)
print(res)
```

will output `['1', '0.2', '3', '4', '5']`

Please note that this approach won't handle negative numbers correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the notification about negative numbers!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following approach with `re.findall` function:

```
num_str = '1+0.2-(3^4)*5'
numbers = re.findall(r'\d(?=[^.]|$)|\d+\.\d+', num_str)

print(numbers)
```

The output:

```
['1', '0.2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to extract only positive integers, try the following. Ive assumed that were spaces between the simbols and numbers:

```
[int(s) for s in str.split() if s.isdigit()]
```

This is better than the regex example for three reasons: 
You don't need another module, 
It's more readable because you don't need to parse the regex mini-language and
It is faster.

Comment: Yeah, it works if you dont want to distinguish between positive and negative numbers. I think this one-liner solution is better that use regex and reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Even if the numbers and symbols in the string are not separated by space `' '`?

Comment: Ups, you are right @anonymous, i`ve assumed that were spaces between the simbols and numbers in the test i`ve done. Noob error. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: You should mention that with the answer. In case someone might be looking at your answer as reference, they should know the limitations/scope of the answer :)